# mySQL optimization for NxM string search

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Sorry for the generic subject but I couldn't think of anything better :(

Let's say I have a few fixed strings (named s1, s2, ... sn, no more than 5 or 6, four in the example) that I have to check against an already existing table with a few VARCHAR(50) fields (called t1, t2, t3, ... no more than 5, but 4 in the example).
The simple query would look something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE (s1 = t1) or (s1 = t2) or (s1 = t3) or (s1 = t4) OR
                         (s2 = t1) or (s2 = t2) or (s2 = t3) or (s2 = t4) OR
                         (s3 = t1) or (s3 = t2) or (s3 = t3) or (s3 = t4) OR
                         (s4 = t1) or (s4 = t2) or (s4 = t3) or (s4 = t4) OR 
                         (s5 = t1) or (s5 = t2) or (s5 = t3) or (s5 = t4)
```

At first, I was thinking of generating a big string concatenating all the t1+t2+t3+t4 when I am creating the t1,t2... since it does not "cost time" when I create them, and then using some sort of "substr" in mySQL to look for the strings. Something like (again, I do not know mySQL syntax)

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE (s1 in conc) or (s2 in conc) or (s3 in conc) or (s4 in conc) or (s5 in conc)
```

The real problem is about the number of elements in the table.
"tbl" has around 50k elements, and I have to run this query about 10k times with different s1/s2/s3/s4/s5 (I get them from the DB too, but I read them all in memory to fasten things up).

Memory size should not be an issue: each row is about 250 bytes long, so in total the table in RAM could be around 12Mb. Would it make sense to load it in an array, and doing the search directly in RAM? At this point, is there a way to force mySQL server to keep one table in RAM all the time, knowing that it cannot grow too much and 12Mb is a very small amount of memory compared to the time it will save? (I am running the queries from PHP).

Of course, I do not care if the query looks silly or ugly or not elegant. I am looking for something as fast as possible, simply because I will have to run that query as said for about 500k times. Any advice on indexes and such is welcome too :)

PS: Right now I am thinking of doing it once every 24h in a CRON job at 4AM, but it would be nice to be able to do it on demand and without stopping the server for 10 minutes... (one millisecond each is 500s, thus almost 9 minutes of 100% CPU time...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want performance, then you need to use indexes.  Unfortunately, `or` tends to impede the use of indexes.

One solution is the following.  Create an index on each of the columns -- independently, so you one for each "t" field.  Then structure the *constant* strings so you can use `in`.  Phrase the query as:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE t1 in (s1, s2, s3,  . . .) 
UNION
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE t2 in (s1, s2, s3,  . . .) 
UNION
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE t3 in (s1, s2, s3,  . . .) 
UNION
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE t4 in (s1, s2, s3,  . . .) 
UNION
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE t5 in (s1, s2, s3,  . . .)
```

MySQL should use an index for each subquery.  The `union` incurs overhead by removing duplicates.  Presumably, this is possible with comparisons on different fields.

An alternative approach is to use `MATCH() . . . AGAINST` with a full text index.  You can read more about these [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

Comment: Back with the results. With a dataset of 10k rows, it takes about 320ms on the (slow) server I am using. It is basically independent from how many "union" I use and how many "s1..sn" and how many "t1..tn" (I tried from 3 to 10), so that's good. But when I tried my simple query, it gave me the EXACT SAME timings! And I tried all of them multiple times to take caching into consideration too. Then, running "explain" on the new one, it said "Using sort_union(tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4); Using where" so I guess that's the reason why I get the same results... Your query is easier to generate though! Thanks

Comment: Tried with 50k rows. I was expecting almost a linear increase, but the time increase is about 5 to 10% on average. So, I guess it means it's not the query itself, but the time it takes to load the whole table into RAM...